# Help to identify odd diodes, Vf=1.33V @3.9mA

Tags: diodes

I just came across a pair of unusual diodes used as clipping diodes for a compressor/distortion pedal for guitar (Guyatone PS-011).

Vf=1.33V @3.91mA.

Can this be two silicon diodes connected in series internally?

[image: Diodes]